# VS Code Autocomplete suggestion taking up to 6s to display

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules

I took the minimum of files for this scenario to works, which is an `app.js` and a folder with `models/test.js`

The `app.js` is empty and the `models/test.js` is a simple Mongoose model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const testSchema = new Schema({
    // General
    language: String,
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'dates.created', updatedAt: 'dates.modified' } })

const Test = mongoose.model('Tests', testSchema);
module.exports = Test;
```

I found two scenarios that speed up the suggestion :

- Commenting the `module.exports = Test;` in the model and going back to the empty `app.js` makes it instantaneous
- Removing the `node_modules` folder

If I uncomment the module export or add any package (tested with 4 different npm package), the suggestion becomes again very slow

Observations :

- The CPU also goes up by 15% when this happens
- Disabling all extension didn't change the behaviour.
- Reproduced on my PC and Macbook Pro.
- I don't think I noticed this behaviour a few months ago.

[Video showing everything (1min 8s)](https://youtu.be/F6ugGN7i4X4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to have been fixed with more recent updates